# Tree Structure From Underscore Delimited Strings

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I need to convert strings as such:

```
Process1_Cat1_Cat2_Value1
Process1_Cat1_Cat2_Value2
Process2_Cat1_Cat2_Value1
```

into a nested array as such:

```
 var d = [{
        text: 'Process1',
        children: [{
            text: 'Cat1',
            children: [{
                text: 'Cat2',
                children: [{
                    text: 'Value1'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Value2'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },

    {
        text: 'Process2',
        children: [{
            text: 'Cat1',
            children: [{
                text: 'Cat2',
                children: [{
                    text: 'Value1'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },


];
```

The reason why I need to do this is to make use of a treeview to display my data:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-tree-view

I have looked at the following solution but was not able to get it working due to lowdash library throwing errors on the findWhere function:

> Uncaught TypeError: _.findWhere is not a function

http://brandonclapp.com/arranging-an-array-of-flat-paths-into-a-json-tree-like-structure/

See below for the code:

```
function arrangeIntoTree(paths, cb) {
    var tree = [];

    // This example uses the underscore.js library.
    _.each(paths, function(path) {

        var pathParts = path.split('_');
        pathParts.shift(); // Remove first blank element from the parts array.

        var currentLevel = tree; // initialize currentLevel to root

        _.each(pathParts, function(part) {

            // check to see if the path already exists.
            var existingPath = _.findWhere(currentLevel, {
                name: part
            });

            if (existingPath) {
                // The path to this item was already in the tree, so don't add it again.
                // Set the current level to this path's children
                currentLevel = existingPath.children;
            } else {
                var newPart = {
                    name: part,
                    children: [],
                }

                currentLevel.push(newPart);
                currentLevel = newPart.children;
            }
        });
    });

    cb(tree);
}


arrangeIntoTree(paths, function(tree) {
    console.log('tree: ', tree);
});
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where's the Javascript? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Did I not mention in the code that I used the only solution that I could find at http://brandonclapp.com/arranging-an-array-of-flat-paths-into-a-json-tree-like-structure/, however, could not get it working?  Do you want me to post the same code here?

Comment: "I found this code here which doesn't work" isn't the same as trying to write code to solve the problem yourself - to start, try writing some code on your own :)

Comment: btw, i see no tree structure oif the fist two string, which have common parents.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for picking that up, fixed it

Comment: @CertainPerformance apologies for not being as good as you are.  Believe me I did try.  I'm new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative by looking for the `text` at the actual level. If not found create a new object. Return the children array for the next level until the most nested array. Then add the leaf object.

```js
var data = ['Process1_Cat1_Cat2_Value1', 'Process1_Cat1_Cat2_Value2', 'Process2_Cat1_Cat2_Value1'],
    result = data.reduce((r, s) => {
        var keys = s.split('_'),
            text = keys.pop();
    
        keys
            .reduce((q, text) => {
                var temp = q.find(o => o.text === text);
                if (!temp) {                    
                    q.push(temp = { text, children: [] });
                }
                return temp.children;
            }, r)
            .push({ text });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That is some serious javascript Kung Fu.  Thanks man you really helped me out here!